# GAS FormApp add data to form response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to add the title of a google form to it's response so that the said data is written to the spreadsheet when a user submits the form.

I believe I need to use `withItemResponse(response)`

So far this is what I came up with.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var title = form.getTitle();
  var formResponse = form.getResponses();
  var items = form.getItems();
  formResponse.withItemResponse(items[5].asTextItem().createResponse(title).submit()); 
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Would you please give an example of how a successful outcome would appear on the Form Response sheet.

Comment: "I believe I need to use withItemResponse(response)" How it is that you believe this is the case. The documentation says `withItemResponse(response)` is used to [programmatically submit a response to the form](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withitemresponseresponse) - i.e. script created responses But, as I understand it, you want the title to appear in conventional "human" responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit programmatically a user response (Throws an "Sorry, this response has already been submitted." exception). The submit() [1] function is for responses that aren't submitted yet (programmatically made).

However, you can create a on form submit trigger for the target Spreadsheet [2][3] (The one linked to the form) and get the title from the form to insert it in the column you wish (I used the 7th column):

```
function onUserFormSubmit(e) {
  //Get Form from formID and title
  var form = FormApp.openById("[FORM-ID]");
  var title = form.getTitle();
  //Row where user response is inserted
  var responseRow = e.range.getRow();
  //Column where you want the title to be
  var titleColumn = 7;

  //Get responses sheet and insert the title in the given cell
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  sheet.getSheetByName("Form responses 1").getRange(responseRow, titleColumn).setValue(title);  
}

function createTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("[SPREADSHEET-ID]");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("onUserFormSubmit")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#submit()

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events